# How to find special characters using code dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can i use this select query in my code to get special characters for each columns dynamically ? this select query works fine in sql but in this code how can i pass this select query by using dynamic sql?

```
DECLARE
  r_emp   SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST   := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST();
  v_array SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
     'cust_name',
     'BILL_DELIVER_METHOD'
  );
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
  FOR i IN 1..v_array.COUNT LOOP
    r_emp.EXTEND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM customer_profile WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE('||v_array(i)||','[A-Za-z0-9.]')' 
         INTO r_emp(i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_array(i) || ': ' || r_emp(i));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Error report -

> ```
> ORA-06550: line 12, column 86:
> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "[" when expecting one of the following:
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I see big problem with the string

```
'select count(1) from customer_profile where not regexp_like('||v_array(i)||','[A-Za-z0-9.]')'
```

It looks like that you want to use regexp_like(something,'[A-Za-z0-9.]') dynamically, but the ' breaks the string.
Use escape for it: '' inside the string translates to '

'Anna''s diary' ==> **Anna's diary**

Try

```
'select count(1) from customer_profile where not regexp_like('||v_array(i)||',''[A-Za-z0-9.]'')'
```